# DateSerial overflow with dates greater than 17/09/2059

Tags: vb6

I am currently working on a VB6 project that handles event data transmit by UK rail stock. Occasionally the trains 'gets confused' about the date and will transmit events dated wildly in the future, I have seen events dated as far as 2088. The date is transmit as Unix time (seconds from 1/1/1970).

I understand what the issue is, i am just struggling to find a solution. The issue appears to be when the date exceeds '17/09/2059' it overflows the integer used for the 'day' that DateSerial can handle. The code below is the line where the overflow occurs, so when 'intDays+1' is > 32767.

```
UnixTimestampToDateTime = DateSerial(1970, 1, intDays + 1) + TimeSerial(intHours, intMins, CInt(intSecs))
```

The goal is to convert Unix time into the following format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss". Can i get DateSerial to work beyond this date limitation or do i need to completely change how i calculate the date? Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Its a Currency. Cheers.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: How are you breaking down the unix timestamp into days, hours and minutes?

Comment: Aplogies im trying to figure out how to post code in a comment, only just joined SO.

Comment: You don't; comments are for clarifying the question. If there is new pertinent info, update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize your result to 01/01/1970 and then add the required seconds:

```
Dim unix_time As Currency
Dim max_long  As Long
Dim result    As Variant

' Determine unix time
unix_time = .....

' Initialize result to 01/01/1970 00:00:00
result = DateSerial(1970, 1, 1) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)

' Determine maximum number of seconds we can add in a single call
max_long = 2147483647

' Add desired time
While unix_time > max_long
  result = DateAdd("s", max_long, result)
  unix_time = unix_time - max_long
Wend
result = DateAdd("s", CLng(unix_time), result)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, this is actually 1 of the first things i tried. The problem is that this also overflows. Using Dateadd to add seconds from 1/1/1970 will only reach 01/19/2038 @ 3:14am (UTC), so any time the train transmits over 2147483647 will cause this to overflow also :-(

Comment: I updated my answer. Don't know whether this works; I didn't try

Comment: Hi Robert, that works perfectly. Thank you for your assistance. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is quite trivial to come up with a replacement version of `DateSerial` that accepts `Long` for days, e.g. try this:

```
Private Function MyDateSerial(ByVal Year As Integer, ByVal Month As Integer, ByVal Day As Long)
    MyDateSerial = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1) + Day - 1
End Function
```

Here is a simple use-case to test it

```
Debug.Print MyDateSerial(1970, 1, 30000), DateSerial(1970, 1, 30000)
19.2.2052     19.2.2052
```